Kalman Filter with correlated observation noise and identity observation matrix
My Kalman Filter model is very simple, I have a identity transition matrix and identity observation matrix.
State transition: $x_t = x_{t-1} + v_t$ where $v_t \sim N(0,Q)$. The states kind of follow a random walk (there is still correlation between states).
Observation: $z_t = x_t + w_t$. I can have a noisy observation of the individual state. But different from the conventional Kalman Filter where observation noise is white, my $w_t$ is actually very autocorrelated. If my current observation overestimate the state, my next observation likely does.
I have been thinking about how to solve this problem. As a standard solution, we can add a state to model the "colored noise", but I wonder if there is an easier approach. Adding states is too expensive for me.
I read Kalman filtering correlated measurements which is almost precisely the problem I have, but the answer doesn't really solve the problem. The problem says "The measurements are made by integrating over time", but the solution provides a measurement of the "velocity", which is what you integrate over, not the final integration.  It also involves augmenting the states.
I am thinking of applying a Riccati equation similar to the asymptoptic Kalman Filter. The idea is that suppose my observation $z$ remains the same the whole time.  Assume I run the KF with assumption that the observation noise is white. If I update my filter every 1 microsecond, it will quickly converge to $z$ with high conviction. But if I update my filter every 1 hour, it'd take a long time. But no matter I update my filter every 1 microsecond or every 1 hour, the final matrix $P$ should be the same. So I just solve the Riccati Equation with $P_{\infty} = R$, and back out an R. It is solvable if my $H$ matrix is identity.
[EDIT] The noise is something like $w_t=w_{t−1}+N(0,R)$. I understand I can augment the states to model this $w_t$
but I do wonder what's wrong with my approach
I tried, and it doesn't work.... but I don't understand what's wrong with my solution, and how I should fix it.

Do you know the nature of $w_t$? Is it auto correlated but Gaussian, uniform, etc.? Also, do you know the auto correlation function? Is it stationary, etc.?

@obareey It's something like $w_t = w_{t-1} + N(0,R)$. I understand I can augment the states to model this $w_t$ but I do wonder what's wrong with my approach

The state augmentation would be the first strategy that would come to mind for me as well. My other thought is that you could use the post-update x_t to estimate w_t, and then subtract that off at the following time step? It probably won't be optimal, but computationally super cheap.

Hi Geroge: Just curious: if you added $w_t$ as a state, why is it expensive ? It's just a vector update instead of a scalar update ?

@markleeds my states are already a lot. and matrix multiplication is $O(n^3)$. If I double my states they get 8 times slower

Oh. I see what you mean by the slowness.  I used to deal with the KF so I looked around a bit and found this. I don't know if it can definitely help but it looks related as far as the observation equation having serially correlated noise. I hope it helps. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670025416/downloads/19670025416.pdf

The Kalman filter would not work with your problem (and I doubt there exists anything that can work). Since your measurement noise depend on the previous noise value in the same way, you lose observability property. You can see this easily by augmenting the states and checking the observability matrix.
You can also understand this intuitively. To correctly estimate $x_t$ from $z_t$, you would have to guess the value of $w_t$. This would be easy in the case of white noise, since you know the values average out to $0$ in the long run and the measurements are independent from each other. However, in your case there is no way to estimate it just from $z_t$. There is infinitely many possible estimates for $x_t$ and $w_t$ that gives the same $z_t$.

"Since the measurement noise depends on the previous noise value" I think this is too specific.  It's because each depends on the previous value in the same way -- then you lose observability.  If $w_k = \mathbf F_w w_{k-1} + N(0, R)$, $x_k = \mathbf F_x x{k-1} + N(0, Q)$, and $F_k \ne F_x$ then the resulting system would still be observable.  It may even be observable if $F_x = F_w$ but have stable eigenvalues -- I'm not sure of that without working it out, though.

@TimWescott you are right. I edited my answer. As a side node, if all of the unobservable states are stable, then the system is called detectable and one can still use Kalman Filter.
